# LINQ create sorting expression basis property of class, support in EF Core

Tags: c#, linq

When using LINQ `OrderBy` to order by property that is a class type, I would like the collection to be ordered by the values of one of the properties of the class type.  How do I control this, while being able to be translated into SQL query by EF Core?

```c
public class FooDate
{
    public DateTime DateTime {get; set;}
    public bool UserSetValue {get; set;}
    // other properties
}
public class Bar
{
    public FooDate Date {get; set;}
    // other properties
}
```

When I would order by the property that is of class type:

```c
List<Bar> sortedInstances = existingList.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();
```

I would like that the collection is ordered by values of `FooDate.DateTime`.

Update:

I tried to to implement `IComparable` but it did not translate to SQL in EF Core.

```c
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return 1;

    FooDate other = obj as FooDate;
    if (other != null)
        return this.DateTime.CompareTo(other.DateTime);
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a FooDate");
}
```

Comment: *"the property is of a class type"* - is the class represent a row in the table? if yes, it should work.. i reckon old EF would do a join for this.

Comment: Yes, the property of type `FooDate` is configured as owned.  It has a number of properties and I want to control which property is used for the comparison.   To be clear: the first query fails to be translated to SQL, the second is correctly translated. EF Core 6.

Comment: ah, i misinterpreted your statement, my bad. you want to `OrderBy` **using** a class. it cant be done, c# by itself can order arbitrary class without clue (e.g. `IComparable<T>`). even more so arbitrary rows in the table, there is no well defined natural order in sql. you can syntatically cheat a bit using extension method to translate `.OrderBy(x => x.Date)` to `.OrderBy(x => x.Date.DateTime)` though. alternatively you can resort to intercepting linq-to-sql translation (cumbersome solution).

Comment: Do you build `OrderBy` dynamically by yourself? Which field from class should be selected? Any convention?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv The expression used in `OrderBy` is dynamically created with `Expression`. For each property that is allowed to be sorted, an entry in dictionary will be created, which would hold a lambda expression.  For example for `Bar` its dictionary would show `{"date", x => x.Date}` (the http query has the properties in camelcase).

Comment: I could add the logic that is specific to `FooDate` in my expression creation method, but I'd rather manage it in the relevant class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to start with, make an interface that indicates the type has an expression that it can be compared using:

```
public interface IComparableExpression<TObject>
{
    static abstract Expression<Func<TObject, object>> Comparer { get; }
}
```

And implement it on your class:

```
public class FooDate : IComparableExpression<FooDate>
{
    // other properties

    public static Expression<Func<FooDate, object>> Comparer => fooDate => fooDate.DateTime;
}
```

Then make your own versions of the `OrderBy` that constrains the key to having its own comparer:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> OrderByComparable<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> query, 
    Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> selector)
    where TKey : IComparableExpression<TKey>
{
    return query.OrderBy(selector.Compose(TKey.Comparer));
}
```

While you're at it, you probably also want `ThenBy` and `Descending` versions of each:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> OrderByDescendingComparable<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> query,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> selector)
    where TKey : IComparableExpression<TKey>
{
    return query.OrderByDescending(selector.Compose(TKey.Comparer));
}
public static IQueryable<TSource> ThenByComparable<TSource, TKey>(this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> query, 
    Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> selector)
    where TKey : IComparableExpression<TKey>
{
    return query.ThenBy(selector.Compose(TKey.Comparer));
}
public static IQueryable<TSource> ThenByDescendingComparable<TSource, TKey>(this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> query,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> selector)
    where TKey : IComparableExpression<TKey>
{
    return query.ThenByDescending(selector.Compose(TKey.Comparer));
}
```

This relies on the following method to compose two expressions:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> Compose<TSource, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TSource, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    var intermediateValue = first.Body.ReplaceParameter(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var body = second.Body.ReplaceParameter(second.Parameters[0], intermediateValue);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(body, param);
}
public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression,
    ParameterExpression toReplace,
    Expression newExpression)
{
    return new ParameterReplaceVisitor(toReplace, newExpression)
        .Visit(expression);
}
public class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression from;
    private Expression to;
    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

And now you have the tools for your (mostly) original desired code:

```
List<Bar> sortedInstances = existingList.OrderByComparable(x => x.Date).ToList();
```

Which will, behind the scenes, construct something equivalent to:

```
List<Bar> sortedInstances = existingList.OrderBy(x => x.Date.DateTime).ToList();
```